# How to use setters on a object in an array(java)

Tags: java, arrays, object, setter

I'm trying to set an objects variables in an array with setters but I keep getting
build errors. this is what I have tied

```
Sandwich[] newSandwich = new Sandwich[5];

newSandwich[0].setMainIngredient("Chicken");
newSandwich[0].setBread("Brown");
newSandwich[0].setPrice(7.00);
```

Comment: let me guess.... NullPointer? Nothing else you would get with your code

Comment: At least post the errors you are getting...

Comment: It's probably not a build error but a runtime error in the shape of a NullPointerException. We even have to guess your problem.

Answer (score 7):

if you call element 0 in your array you have to create it before calling the setter method of the object:

```
Sandwich[] newSandwich = new Sandwich[5];

newSandwich[0] = new Sandwich();
newSandwich[0].setMainIngredient("Chicken");
newSandwich[0].setBread("Brown");
newSandwich[0].setPrice(7.00);
```

in the first line you only create an `array` for objects of class `Sandwich`.
Not the object `Sandwich` itselfs.

you have todo it for each element you are calling in the array. 
I suggest a loop to create the objects:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
   newSandwich[i] = new Sandwich();
}
```